# Creating a PHP SoapClient request

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I have a SOAP service that is expecting a request like so:

```
<soap:body>
  ...
  <request>
    <MemberIds>
      <MemberId>string</MemberId>
      <MemberId>string</MemberId>
    </MemberIds>
    <foo>string</foo>
  </request>
  ...
</soap:body>
```

`Foo` is working correctly but I having problems populating the MemberIds section.

Whatever I seem to do, no `MemberId` property is included in the request. I have tried:

```
array(
  'MemberIds' => '1',
  'foo' => 'bar'
)

array(
  'MemberIds' => array('1'),
  'foo' => 'bar'
)

array(
  'MemberIds' => array('MemberId' => '1'),
  'foo' => 'bar'
)
```

...all of which populate `foo` but no `MemberIds`. I am currently only trying to use one MemberId at a time but I can't see how I could construct this using multiple named `MemberId`s without manually creating the XML as I can't have sibling items with the same name - and I can't get it working with one item yet! Any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Well now I just feel silly. It was MemberId but I was using MemberID. Because this didn't match the specification, SoapClient was completely stripping it out.

I would delete the question but I'm sure someone else will have the same problem. Probably me again in 6 months.

Answer (score 0):

With this all should be working.

```
$array =  array();
$array['MemberIds'][0]['MemberId']  =  1;
$array['foo'] =  'bar';
```

No error message is returned?